# how to add vector object to sharedpreference?

Tags: android, vector, sharedpreferences

I need to know the best way to add and get a `Vector` object to the `SharedPreference` in `android`.

I have vector with items for username and their corresponding status.The status is `boolean`.Suppose i have this vector with respective status for 10 users.I want to know how to add this vector to the `SharedPreference` of my application. i will do the `get` and use it for processing in different part.Kindly help me to do the get and set for this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

First, `Vector` has been considered to be obsolete for ~15 years. Use `ArrayList` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, depending upon your threading requirements.

Second, `SharedPreferences` has no built-in means of storing a collection, other than a `Set<String>`.

You are welcome to:

- Convert your data structure into a string (e.g., JSON) and store the string in `SharedPreferences`; or
- Use a "numbered keys" approach, so a `SharedPreferences` key of `stuff.0.username` points to the 0th username, `stuff.0.status` points to the 0th status, `stuff.1.username` points to the 1st username, and so on; or
- Use some other data persistence approach (e.g., SQLite database, JSON file) that may be more amenable to your data structure.

Comment: ok thanks. i will try these ways...  can you tell me why vector is not  a good option?

Comment: @JVN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated